# MMS images do not work in Google Messenger

Tags: sms, mms, google-messages

I am using Google Messenger application as my default text messenger application. I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4.

When I get text messages that have images, the image stays frozen at "downloading..." and will not complete. After a period of time, the image just fails.

When I change to the Samsung Messaging application, text images will properly arrive.

I have tried clearing defaults, and doing a factory reset, the reinstalling Google Messenger.

EDIT:

This is the app I am referring to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en

Comment: This is almost always an APN or carrier issue. Check APN settings regarding MMS. Most carrier subsidized phones have this hard coded in the app, you may need to enter the manual MMS APN information in Messenger's settings

Comment: there is no APN settings in Messenger

Comment: Then you will have to build a correct MMS APN in the system settings. What carrier (please don't say Verizon... please don't say Verizon...)

Comment: But why do other messaging applications work?

Comment: All other apps work, or just the app that was bundles with the phone.

Comment: The bundled samsung messenger and 3rd party textra work. Google messenger does not.

Comment: No clue... I installed it on my Moto X Pure and it worked fine, MMS send/received pictures with no issues.

Comment: Well I would assume MMS is not broken on google messenger across all devices and carriers LOL.